# curves on abelian surface $E\times E$, part II

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

It is Chapter II Exercise 4.16.4 in [Kollár](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-03276-3), and we are working on $\mathbb{C}$. Let $E$ be a very general smooth elliptic curve and consider the abelian surface $X=E\times E$. Let $m,n$ be coprime integers and define the closed subspace $E_{m,n}\subset X$ be the image of
$$E\rightarrow E\times E,\quad x\mapsto(mx,nx)$$
These $E_{m,n}$ are all curves. According to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4484109/curves-on-abelian-surface-e-times-e), $E_{1,0},E_{0,1},E_{1,1}$ is a basis of the group of one-cycles on $X$ and $E_{m,n}^2=0$.

> Show that every irreducible curve $C$ with $C.C=0$ is a translate of some $E_{m,n}$.

Comment: I am bit confused, since it doesn't seem possible to translate $E_{1,0}$ to $E_{m,n}$ for some $m,n>0$ coprime. Any translate of $E_{1,0}$ is of the form $E \times \{p\}$ unless I am mistaken

Comment: @NickL I think it should be the translation on abelian variety but not the real translation, I will check it back again.

Comment: Which chapter does the exercise come from? The chapter IV exercise 4.16.6 is not the one that you mentioned.

Comment: @AGlearner It is a typo, it is indeed exercise 4.16.4 in Chaper II. page 130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra condition of $E$ in Kollar's book. Namely, the elliptic curve $E$ is *very general* in the moduli. Otherwise, for example, if $E=\mathbb C/\mathbb Z+\omega_3\mathbb Z$, where $\omega_3=\exp(2\pi i/3)$. Then the curve given by $E\to E\times E$, $x\to (x,\omega_3 x)$ contributing an extra Picard factor and is not a translate of $E_{m,n}$. The same assumption is needed in your previous question as well.

The extra assumption should be understood as the elliptic curve $E$ is not defined over a quadratic number field. In particular $$Hom(E, E)=\mathbb Z\tag{*}\label{*}.$$

Therefore

$$Hom(E, E\times E)=Hom(E, E)\times Hom(E, E)\cong \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z.$$

The image is just your $E_{m,n}$. So it suffices to show

**Claim.** Any irredubible curve $C$ in $E\times E$ with $C\cdot C=0$ implies $C\cong E$.

> Proof. First by adjunction formula, $2g_a(C)-2=C\cdot C+C\cdot K=0$,
> where $g_a$ is the arithmetic genus. So
> $g_a(C)=1$, and by the assumption that $C$ is irreducible, $C$ is
> either a nodal rational curve or an elliptic curve.
>
> If $C$ is singular, then composite with the normalization $\mathbb P^1=\tilde{C}\to C\to E\times E$ has to be constant, contradicting the
> assumption that $C$ is a curve in $E\times E$. So $C\cong E'$ must be
> a smooth elliptic curve.
>
> Supposedly, $E'$ is isogenous to $E$, but the condition \eqref{*}
> guarantees that $E'\cong E$ is an isomorphism. See the proof [in this
> post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174511).

Comment: I am confused, $E_{m,n}$ is defined only for $m,n>0$ coprime. So we need to show $E_{1,0}$ is a "translate" of some $E_{m,n}$ with $m,n >0 $ coprime. This is a literal reading of the question of the OP, I cannot see the book of Kollar.

Comment: @NickL That's another misrepresentation by OP. In Kollar, $m,n$ are pair of coprime integers.